# Terminology for asking a question "by proxy"

Tags: terminology

A common strategy that is sometimes used when a person asks questions that pertains to themselves, but wants to disassociate from (for any reason), is to frame the question as being about somebody *else*, or otherwise externalizing it. "My friend" is a classic example of this:

> A friend of mine wrecked into their boss's brand new car in the parking lot. What should they do?

Another example often starts with "let's say", presenting a real situation as a hypothetical one in order to artificially distance the asker from a questionable 
 situation:

> Let's say a teacher unfairly gave a student a poor grade on an assignment. How can that student get revenge?

Note that we assume through context that the above examples actually pertain directly to the asker (i.e. they do because I said they do, it's the basis of this question).

Is there a name for this strategy / style of presentation (applies to both speaking and writing) / whatever it is? I'm not even certain that "by proxy" was the correct phrase to use in the title.

Comment: *On behalf of*, though the in-joke on the internet is simply "... I'm asking for a friend".

Comment: @DanBron *On behalf of* is a great example of this. But just to be clear to others: I'm actually wondering about how to *describe* this strategy, rather than looking for ways to *construct* these types of questions myself.

Comment: Also have a look at [trial balloons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_balloon) and the TV Trope called [trial balloon question](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TrialBalloonQuestion).

Comment: I've accepted this as a duplicate because it definitely is. In reading those answers I'm a little sad that none of them seem sufficient (oh well), but it is definitely the same question.

Comment: Look up *prosopopoeia*.

Comment: @JasonC You're welcome. Yes, the answers on the other page don't quite hit the mark. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful, though vickyace's suggestion looks good. You or she can post it as an answer to the other question.

Comment: @vickyace Looked up. Clicked "character mask" because why not. Wikipedia hole entered. Browser tab count growing exponentially. If I don't return within a week, don't come looking for me.